# Joining to the last row in a table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to join two tables the calving table and milking table; In calving table one animal can have several calving date, i want to pick the last appropriate date and join my two  tables so that every milk record has the correct calving date.

My two tables are as follows:

calving table called calving

```
animalid calvingdate
    '1', '1990-12-24'
    '1', '1994-08-19'
    '1', '1997-01-01'
    '2', '1997-01-22'
    '2', '1999-01-13'
```

Milking table called testmilking

```
animalid   milkdate    milkyield
    '1', '1997-02-19', '17.90'
    '1', '1997-03-21', '18.00'
    '1', '1998-05-01', '13.70'
```

The query i am using to generate my summary

```
SELECT testmilking.animalid,calvingdate,milkdate, milkyield FROM testmilking 
INNER JOIN calving on testmilking.animalid = calving.animalid
GROUP BY concat(animalid,calvingdate,milkdate)
```

The right output should be as follows, the date difference between the calving and milking date should be less than 500

```
animalid calvingdate milkdate, milkyield 
'1','1997-01-01', '1998-05-01', '13.70'
```

Create statements

test day

```
CREATE TABLE `testmilking` (
  `AnimalId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MilkDate` date NOT NULL,
  `MilkYield` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL),
  PRIMARY KEY (`AnimalId`,`MilkDate`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKAnimal_TestMilking` FOREIGN KEY (`AnimalId`) REFERENCES `animal` (`AnimalId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

calving table

```
CREATE TABLE `calving` (
  `AnimalId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CalvingDate` date NOT NULL),
  CONSTRAINT `FKAnimal_Calving` FOREIGN KEY (`AnimalId`) REFERENCES `animal` (`AnimalId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please add the current & expected output.

Comment: Why `milkyield` is `17.90` and not `13.70` in your expected output?

Comment: honest mistake @HarshilDoshi

Comment: What happens if there are more than 1 milking date within 500 days of the max calving date? What happens if there are no milking dates within 500 days of the max calving date?

Comment: You only want one row in the result?

Answer (score 0):

You should use simple `DATEDIFF` in you `JOIN` condition. It returns number of days between two dates (note that you should have proper datatype applied to your date columns!):

```
SELECT testmilking.animalid,max(calvingdate),milkdate, milkyield FROM testmilking 
INNER JOIN calving on testmilking.animalid = calving.animalid
AND ABS(DATEDIFF(calvingdate, milkdate)) < 500
group by testmilking.animalid, milkdate, milkyield
```

Comment: This query duplicate s the milk records given that you could have several dates that are under 500 @Michal

Comment: @MirieriMogaka I updated query to use grouping, so you will have one record. I used `MAX` as aggregate, but you can change it to any aggregate function that will meet your requirements.

Comment: grouping truncates the duplicates but i want to display null values for when animal has no proper calving date @Michal Turczyn

Comment: @MirieriMogaka Then use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.animalid, 
      t1.calvingdate,
       t2.milkdate,
       milkyield
from (select animalid, max(calvingdate)
              from claving
              group by animalid
      )t1                  
join (Select animalid,milkdate, milkyield
      from testmilking 
      where (animalid, milkdate) in 
                         (Select animalid, max(milkdate)
                          from testmilking 
                          group by animalid
                         )
     ) t2
on t1.animalid = t2.animalid
where ABS(DATEDIFF(calvingdate, milkdate)) < 500
```

Comment: This query duplicates the milk records given that you could have several dates that are under 500

Comment: can you provide your create/insert queries or create a fiddle to test?

Comment: I am fetching only 1 row for each `animalId`. It shouldn't cause any duplication. Can you give the data for this scenario?

Comment: yes but that sample data doesn't have several dates with 500 day difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one,

```
SELECT testmilking.animalid,max(calvingdate),max(milkdate),(SELECT milkyield FROM 
testmilking WHERE milkdate=MAX(milkdate)) as milkyield FROM testmilking 
LEFT JOIN calving on testmilking.animalid = calving.animalid and
ABS(DATEDIFF(calvingdate, milkdate)) < 500
GROUP BY calvingdate,milkdate,testmilking.animalid
```

Comment: This query duplicates the milk records given that you could have several dates that are under 500  @aishwarya